# $httpProvider Authorization Headers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, api, http-headers, angular-services

I'm try to add a default header for the $http service, which value is an access token that will be generated after user authentification.

```
      .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');

  }]) 

 .factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function () {
          return {
            request: function (config) {
              config.headers = {

                'Authorization': sessionStorage.token}
              return config;
            }
          };
        })
```

But Angular doesn't accept the header : A`ccess-Control-Request-He...   authorization`.
I try with `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'` and lot of other but nothing works.
I tested the API with Rest Console and she accepts the header.

The problem comes from my application ...

**Response**

```
- Access-Control-Allow-Head...  Accept,Origin,Authorization,Content-Type,X-Requested-With
 - Access-Control-Allow-Meth... GET, POST, PUT, DELETE   
   Access-Control-Allow-Orig... *
 - Access-Control-Expose-Hea... Authorization Cache-Control no-store,   
   no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

**Request**

```
- Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
 - Accept-Encoding  gzip, deflate
 - Accept-Language  en-us,en;q=0.5
 - **Access-Control-Request-He...   authorization**
 - Access-Control-Request-Me... GET
 - Connection   keep-alive
 - Host api.mysite.com
 - Origin   http://xxxxx.com:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

The application Works on my domain api ! It's a problem with CORS. Is it possible that situe on my server ? With htacess ? Because i have header allow-origin : * in my api...

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this on your .htaccess
Header set   Access-Control-Allow-Origin        "*"
Header set   Access-Control-Allow-Headers       "Authorization, Content-Type"